# Как задать шрифт в RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends 
                     RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    TextView info;
    ArrayList<String> posts;

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                      .inflate(R.layout.recycler_child,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.info.setText(posts.get(position));
        Linkify.addLinks(holder.info, Linkify.ALL);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView info;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            info = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        }

    }
```

Как установить шрифт для `Textview` из `assets/font` ?

Comment: This is SO in russian. Please translate question to russian

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду разный шрифт? Или один и тот же?

Answer (score 0):

Довольно просто. Правда для этого будет необходимо передать `Context` в `RecyclerAdapter` в данном случае.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.info.setText(posts.get(position));
    //Установка шрифта
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "your_font.ttf");
    holder.info.setTypeface(font);

    Linkify.addLinks(holder.info, Linkify.ALL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создать класс, расширяющий `TextView`

```
public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "TextView";

    public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);  
        return true;
    }   
}
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="TextViewPlus">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?Layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.example.TextViewPlus
    android:id="@+id/textViewPlus1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/showingOffTheNewTypeface"
    foo:customFont="saxmono.ttf">
</com.example.TextViewPlus>
</LinearLayout>
```